# EF Code-First How To Read A From Table With A Composite Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I have created a SQL Server table using EntityFramework 6 Code First that has a composite key:  Inspector ID and Jurisdiction ID.  Each combination of those fields should be unique on the table hence the composite key.

Class/Table Definition:

```
public class InspectorJurisdiction
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int inspectorId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int jurisId { get; set; }
    }
```

Web Context:

```
public DbSet<InspectorJurisdiction> InspectorJurisdictions { get; set; }
```

I am using the Repository design pattern to interface with the created table which has a Repository class/interface and web Context.

How do I wire up the

```
var record = context.InspectorJurisdictions.Find(????)
```

statement to use the two fields that make up the composite key to read from the database table?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create entity for many to many mapping. Instead each entity 
`Inspector` and `Jurisdiction` should contain collection of other objects.

For more information how to set it properly check documentation https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I am attempting to define what Inspectors can interact with what Jurisdictions.  I do have entities for Inspectors and Jurisdictions already defined via EF with their own repositories.

Comment: just follow ef documentation, then in `InspectorRepository` in method `Find(id)` include related Jurisdictions: ```context.Inspectors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Include(x => x.Jurisdictions)```